# Demonstrate that the smaller distance between two skew lines is the one perpendicular to both (Linear Algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

My professor of Linear Algebra recently started this demonstration: I have two skew lines $f(t) = x_{0} + t\vec{u}$ and $g(s) = y_{0} + s\vec{v}$ and I know that the perpendicular to the two lines passes by two points $f(\bar{t}), g(\bar{s})$. I want to demonstrate that picked two other points $f(t)$ and $g(s)$:
$||x_{0} + t\vec{u} - y_{0} - s\vec{v}|| > ||x_{0} + \bar{t}\vec{u} - y_{0} - \bar{s}\vec{v}||$ $ \forall t,s \in R:t\neq \bar{t}, s\neq \bar{s}$, 
that is to say the smaller distance between two skew lines is the one that lies on their perpendicular. He gave us this hint: 
$||x_{0} + t\vec{u} - y_{0} -s\vec{v}||^2 = ||x_0 + t\vec{u} - x_0 - \bar{t}\vec{u} + x_0 + \bar{t}\vec{u}-y_0-\bar{s}\vec{v}+y_0 + \bar{s}\vec{v} - y_0-s\vec{v}||^2$ where $(x_0 + \bar{t}\vec{u} - y_0 - \bar{s}\vec{v})$ has to be $\perp$ to both lines for hipothesys. Now what can I do to do demonstrate that all this stuff is $ >||x_0 + \bar{t}\vec{u} - y_0 - \bar{s}\vec{v}||^2$  ?

Comment: split the big thing into perpendicular pieces and use the Pythagorean identity for orthogonal vectors: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem#Inner_product_spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone needs the answer, I'll post here.

$ (t - \bar{t})\vec{u}$ and $(s - \bar{s})\vec{v}$ are the two vectors perpendicular to $x_0 + \bar{t}\vec{u} - y_0 - \bar{s}\vec{v}$ for hypothesis and their sum belongs to their plane, so their sum is perpendicular to $x_0 + \bar{t}\vec{u} - y_0 - \bar{s}\vec{v}$. Now we can use the Pythagorean identity for perpendicular vectors: 
$||((t - \bar{t})\vec{u} + (s - \bar{s})\vec{v}) + (x_0 + \bar{t}\vec{u} - y_0 - \bar{s}\vec{v})||^2 \geqslant ||(t - \bar{t})\vec{u} + (s - \bar{s})\vec{v}||^2 + ||x_0 + \bar{t}\vec{u} - y_0 - \bar{s}\vec{v}||^2 \geqslant ||x_0 + \bar{t}\vec{u} - y_0 - \bar{s}\vec{v}||^2 $ that is what I wanted to prove.